# How do I lock editing the position of faces?

Tags: modeling

I have a large model -- I am going through it and selecting out faces in order to break a large, messy model into smaller sub-parts, so that painting it is hopefully easier

I've locked the position on the object level, but that doesn't seem to translate to the faces, apparently-- it just locks the overall object position.  When I'm in edit mode, right-clicking away on faces, the faces still move around.

(My worry is that when I'm doing a lot of right-clicking to select faces, some small bit is going to get moved without me noticing, and I want to lock face positions for that reason.)

Thanks.

Comment: see if [this helps](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27445/how-to-turn-off-moving-objects-by-holding-rmb)

Comment: or use shape key